# theme-independent CSS/JS files

Tags: theme-development, css, javascript

So far I did the following task to add **theme-dependent** CSS/JS files; I added to the theme's `functions.php` this code, then created the relevant CSS and JS files:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_parent_theme_file_uri() . 'style.css' );
}
add_action( 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 'wp_enqueue_styles' );

function my_theme_enqueue_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'behavior', get_theme_file_uri( 'behavior.js' ), array(), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_assets' );
```

But what if I want my CSS and JS to be **theme-independent**? Say, I want to had a few lines of CSS and JS that will be available in all themes whatsoever.

Is there a way to do so in WordPress **outside the WordPress User Interface**?

Comment: You would need to load them in a plugin.

Comment: Oh crap. Any recommendation?

Comment: No I mean make a plugin that has the stylesheet/scripts and enqueues them.

Comment: I am not a PHP programmer but I do program in Bash and JavaScript so if you'll write an (short?) answer on this, I believe I could understand what's being done. So please do, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to create a simple plugin. Create a directory `tia` inside `plugins` directory and save the code in a file `tia.php` then put it inside `tia` directory and finally activate from plugin page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Theme Independent Assets
 * Author: Obi
 * Version: 0.0.7
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

function tia_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( ... );
    wp_enqueue_style( ... );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tia_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thanks. Must you notify a version like 7.0.0? `null` isn't good? Shouldn't it be 1.0?

Comment: Does the CSS file need to have a special declaration in its top part?

Comment: I like the James Bond code 007! That's why whatever I do I start the version with `0.0.7`. You can use whatever you want. No, the CSS doesn't need any meta comment like the theme `style.css`. Plugin's meta information is stored in plugin main php file, in this plugin the main file is `tia.php`